# Error on a recordset, but same SQL works elsewhere

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

Error: "Run-time error '3061' Too few parameters.  Expected 2.

I wrote this simple function that returns the remaining percentage calculated for number of records changed. It is supposed to occur when the user updates the field called 'percentage' I am certain the code below should work, but obviously something is wrong.  It occurs on the line:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Tier1, [Percentage], Tier3 AS Battalion, Month " _
    & "FROM tbl_CustomPercent " _
    & "WHERE (((Tier1)=[Forms]![frmEntry]![cmbImport_T1]) AND ((Month)=[Forms]![frmEntry]![cmbMonth]));", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

I wonder how it could fail when the very same query is what populates the 'record source' for the form with the 'percentage' textbox.

```
Function RemainingPercentAvailable() As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Tier1, [Percentage], Tier3 AS Battalion, Month " _
& "FROM tbl_CustomPercent " _
& "WHERE (((Tier1)=[Forms]![frmEntry]![cmbImport_T1]) AND ((Month)=[Forms]![frmEntry]![cmbMonth]));", dbOpenSnapshot)

Dim CurrentTotal As Single

CurrentTotal = 0

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        CurrentTotal = CurrentTotal + rs!Percentage
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End If


RemainingPercentAvailable = "Remaing available: " & Format(1 - CurrentTotal, "0.000%")

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt your code to use the `SELECT` statement with a QueryDef, supply values for the parameters, and then open the recordset from the QueryDef.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT Tier1, [Percentage], Tier3 AS Battalion, [Month] " _
    & "FROM tbl_CustomPercent " _
    & "WHERE (((Tier1)=[Forms]![frmEntry]![cmbImport_T1]) AND (([Month])=[Forms]![frmEntry]![cmbMonth]));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL )
' supply values for the 2 parameters ...
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Eval(qdf.Parameters(0).Name)
qdf.Parameters(1).Value = Eval(qdf.Parameters(1).Name)
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Note: `Month` is a reserved word.  Although that name apparently caused no problems before, I enclosed it in square brackets so the db engine can not confuse the field name with the `Month` function.  It may be an unneeded precaution here, but it's difficult to predict exactly when reserved words will create problems.  Actually, it's better to avoid them entirely if possible.

Comment: That worked indeed. Thank you.   I wonder why I have other instances that worked... by chance?

Comment: For those instances where it worked, were you opening the query directly as a DAO.Recordset?

Answer (score 0):

This one is calling a query directly in a DAO.Recordset and it works just fine.
Note the same 'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset) This is a parameter SQL as well. 
The only difference is with this one is that I DIDN'T need to move through and analyze the recordset - but the error occurs on the 'Set rs = " line, so I wasn't able to get further anyway.

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT Sum(tbl_SP.AFP) AS AFP_TOTAL, tbl_SP.T1_UNIT " _
       & "FROM tbl_SP " _
       & "GROUP BY tbl_SP.T1_UNIT " _
       & "HAVING (((tbl_SP.T1_UNIT)='" & strUnit & "'));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

AFP_Total = rs!AFP_Total

Answer (score 0):

There is an even simpler way to calculate the total percentage.

Instead of looping through the records, you can use the DSum() function.

Note that DSum will return Null if there are no records, so you need to wrap it in Nz().

Just for fun, here is your function but written as one single statement:

```
    Function RemainingPercentAvailable() As String
    RemainingPercentAvailable = "Remaining available: " & Format(1 - _
        Nz(DSum("Percentage", _
                "tbl_CustomPercent", _
                "Tier1 = " & QString(cmbImport_T1) & _
                " AND [Month] = " & QString(cmbMonth))) _
        , "0.000%")
    End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend building a temporary parameterized query in VBA, because it makes the code too complicated. And slower. I prefer to build "pure" SQL that will run directly in the db engine without any callbacks to Access. I'm assuming that your function is defined in the frmEntry form, and that `cmbImport_T1` and `cmbMonth` are string fields. If they are numeric, omit `qString()`.

Here is my version of your function. It handles the empty-recordset case correctly.

```
Function RemainingPercentAvailable() As String
Dim CurrentTotal As Double, q As String
q = "SELECT Percentage" & _
    " FROM tbl_CustomPercent" & _
    " WHERE Tier1 = " & QString(cmbImport_T1) & _
    " AND [Month] = " & QString(cmbMonth)
CurrentTotal = 0
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(q)
  While Not .EOF
    CurrentTotal = CurrentTotal + .Fields("Percentage")
    .MoveNext
  Wend
End With
RemainingPercentAvailable = "Remaining available: " & _
                            Format(1 - CurrentTotal, "0.000%")
End Function

' Return string S quoted, with quotes escaped, for building SQL.
Public Function QString(ByVal S As String) As String
   QString = "'" & Replace(S, "'", "''") & "'"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for solving those even though they weren't the title of this question. The operation works nicely.  I was going to ask about the second piece elsewhere, but since you answered, I can't seem to figure out why the calculation is off by 15%.  Try performing it on 6 records with percent values of .25, .1., .1, .2, .2, and .15.  It returns "Remaining available: 15.000%' - can't imagine why - obviously missed something else.

Comment: *You* may "prefer to build 'pure' SQL that will run directly in the db engine", but a blanket recommendation to use dynamic SQL over parameterized queries is simply bad advice. You claim that parameterized queries make the code "more complicated" (than a horrible string concatenation with VBA functions to sanitize and format the arguments?) and "slower" (really? *significantly* and *provably* slower?) while ignoring the advantages of **(1)** protection against SQL injection, **(2)** avoiding literal delimiter errors, **(3)** not having to worry about `dd/mm` vs. `mm/dd` date formatting.

Comment: Monty - It worked for me!  Somehow, you aren't adding the final number into the total. Try adding `debug.print .Fields("Percentage")` just before the .MoveNext and see if you get 0.15 in the output. If you can't duplicate the problem now, then maybe you have a problem with the form. If you recalculate the percentage remaining in a txtPercentage_AfterUpdate event on your form, the new value won't be written to the DB yet. Try adding `Me.Dirty = False` at the start of your event procedure.

Comment: Tom, I used your first 'DSUM' example.
I guess, it would help to know that the form this is calculated on is a 'subform.'  Month and Tier1 are provided on the parent form. I write the 'Remaining Percentage' on a label on the parent form beside the subform.

Comment: It was because the subform lags behind. First I added the 'Me.Dirty = false' then when the routine ends, I do the requery. I tried saving the record that the subform is on so I could go back to it, but it keeps jumping back to the top, after each entry. I almost got bogged down writing something to reposition the cursor when I found Me.Recalc - what a lifesaver.  Thanks everyone.